# How to inject MetaMask using NEthereum using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, blockchain, metamask

I am trying to create website which will interact with MetaMask using ASP.Net with VB.Net and NEthereum as API.

Unfortunately after exploring more than 2 days I am unable to find any such inbuild functionality in NEthereum.

Requirement: On Button Click it must check for MetaMask and if present inject it to access account.

It will be good if anyone will help me with it.

Your help appreciated !!!

Thank in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

regardless of what client your Geth/NetEthereum/Pyethereum your front end javascript will do the handling of web3 activities by pointing to your local running client. Just point your Metamask to local provider and run any client you want